# Placing a picture next to a title for a react bootstrap Tab

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

[React bootstrap Tabs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/) allow us to create tabs.

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey="profile" id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
  <Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
    <Sonnet />
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="profile" title="Profile">
    <Sonnet />
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="contact" title="Contact" disabled>
    <Sonnet />
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

For each `Tab` there is a title `tag` that accepts a `string`. I wonder if it is possible to display a picture instead of the `title`? Or display both? Also, I wish I could display a picture next to the Tab's title.

Answer (score 0):

see the first tab, you have a title and an image one next to each other.

```
<Tab.Container id="left-tabs-example" defaultActiveKey="first">
  <Row>
    <Col sm={3}>
      <Nav variant="pills" className="flex-column">
        <Nav.Item>        
          <Nav.Link eventKey="first">
          Tab 1 
          <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-pxzt5JSmq3o/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAARw/oSQ00wYMa9g/photo.jpg?sz=32"></img>
          </Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey="second">Tab 2</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
      </Nav>
    </Col>
    <Col sm={9}>
      <Tab.Content>
        <Tab.Pane eventKey="first">
          <Sonnet />
        </Tab.Pane>
        <Tab.Pane eventKey="second">
          <Sonnet />
        </Tab.Pane>
      </Tab.Content>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Tab.Container>
```

Comment: Tried your code but Tab.Container moved to be TabContainer etc. Also, I do not understand why Nav.Item is not working for me